# Sistema de seguir e postagem (tipo rede social)

Tags: php, mysql, query, sql-select

Estou a desenvolver um novo projecto e estou a criar um sistema de seguidores de perfil, em que o objectivo é mostrar apenas as publicações de quem eu sigo.
Como por exemplo o de uma rede social.
Eu sigo a pessoa, portanto recebo as publicações dessa pessoa na pagina inicial.
A minha dificuldade está em mostrar apenas as publicações de quem sigo.

Exemplo:

[image: Esquema]

O que eu penso é que tenho de unir as minhas 2 tabelas em apenas 1 query, mas penso nao consigo usar "UNION" de forma nenhuma...
É provavel que esteja no raciocinio errado, me perdoem...
Aqui ficam as minhas tabelas mysql necessarias.
[image: tables]

Já testei varias querys mas nao consegui chegar a uma resolução.
Será melhor fazer 2 querys e comparar com um while ou if?
Se sim... como?
Cumprimentos a todos e obrigado mais uma vez.

PS: Estou a fazer em pdo.

Comment: O problema de PDO é que ele precisa se adequar a qualquer banco de dados, mas nem sempre funciona. Por exemplo, a solução em MySQL é diferente da solução em SQL Server, que tende a ser diferente em PostgreSQL. Genericamente voce faria algo como [SELECT post.* FROM post, follow WHERE follow.userid=post.userid and follow.whofollowid=CODIGO_USER_LOGADO_ATUAL ORDER BY POST.data_registro desc]. Mas você não informou o conteúdo dos campos userid e whofollowid. Eu comparei os userid das duas tabelas, mas talvez seja [WHERE follow.whofollowid=post.userid and follow.userid=CODIGO_USER_LOGADO_ATUAL]

Comment: Pode dizer se funcionou?

Comment: Peço desculpa, so pude voltar hoje. Testarei agora.

Comment: Olá novamente. Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, com algumas alterações funcionou como queria perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. Vou postar em baixo como ficou o codigo.

Comment: SELECT post.* FROM post, follow WHERE follow.whofollowid = post.userid and follow.userid = ? ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time` DESC

Comment: Portanto, eu uso bind's para variaveis que a bind 1 - userid actual logado. = ?, da forma como postou o codigo mostrava os meus post's assim desta forma vai mostrar os post's de quem sigo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Vou transformar em resposta então pra ficar documentado como solução.  Como fiz no comentário, postarei as duas soluções possíveis.

Answer (score 1):

O problema de PDO é que ele precisa se adequar a qualquer banco de dados, mas nem sempre funciona.

Por exemplo, a solução em MySQL é diferente da solução em SQL Server, que tende a ser diferente em PostgreSQL.

Genericamente voce faria algo como

```
SELECT post.* FROM post, follow WHERE follow.userid=post.userid and follow.whofollowid=CODIGO_USER_LOGADO_ATUAL ORDER BY POST.data_registro desc
```

Mas você não informou o conteúdo dos campos userid e whofollowid. Eu comparei os userid das duas tabelas, mas talvez seja invertido, tal como:

```
SELECT post.* FROM post, follow WHERE follow.whofollowid=post.userid and follow.userid=CODIGO_USER_LOGADO_ATUAL
```

Como você mencionou que funcionou para você foi a minha segunda opção que eu tinha postado no comentário (e postei acima também):

```
SELECT post.* FROM post, follow WHERE follow.whofollowid = post.userid and follow.userid = ? ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

Comment: "O problema de PDO é que ele precisa se adequar a qualquer banco de dados, mas nem sempre funciona". A ideia do PDO é padronizar somente a conexão e os métodos de consultas com o banco de dados, e não a implementação com o banco com o SQL. Isso não é exatamente um problemas pois seu propósito não é ser uma [camada de abstração do Banco de Dados](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal)

Comment: Conforme eu tinha dito nos comentários da pergunta, já que a minha solução dada foi utilizada por ele, eu transformei em resposta.

Comment: O comentário é para deixar claro a finalidade do PDO. Ele cumpre o que se propõe a fazer: abstração da camada de acesso aos dados. Não vejo como problema do PDO ter que se adequar aos diversos bancos de dados.